# Copy value from input text to another field

Tags: javascript

so working on a little project to help me learn Javascript so be gently :)

I am creating a little scoreboard which has 2 input values (homeTeam & awayTeam) and i am attempting to copy these to a scorecard variable (Team_1 & Team_2) but can't get this to work. Had this working using a promt and changed as was a bit clunky.

I have been playing around with the below code but cant get this to work, so any help is appreciated.

```
   <label for="home">Home Team</label>
            <input type="text" id="homeInput" name="fname"><br><br>
            <label for="home">Away Team</label>
            <input type="text" id="awayInput" name="fname"><br><br>

            <button onclick="disp_prompt()">Submit Teams</button>
```

```
function disp_prompt(){
    var homeInput = document.getElementById('homeInput').innerHTML = Team_1;
    var awayInput = document.getElementById('awayInput').innerHTML = Team_2;
   
    document.getElementById('homeInput').value = document.getElementById('Team_1').value;     
   
}
```

Comment: What is this- Team_1?

Comment: No, really, what are `Team_1` and `2`? Why you use unsafe inline `on*` handlers? Please [edit] to create a [mcve]. Currently you've just thrown a bunch of unfinished JS at us.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values from the input fields into javascript variables by using the `.value` property of the [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

```
const homeTeam = document.getElementById('homeInput').value;
const awayTeam = document.getElementById('awayInput').value;
```

Unless you are writing [plain javascript code that has to work in old browsers as well](https://caniuse.com/?search=const) (unlikely since you said you are learning) I would recommend using `const` when defining scoped values that won't change (immutable) and `let` when defining scoped variables that can change (mutable). Avoid using `var` unless you actually want to achieve the [var-hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#var_hoisting) effect.

I also added two sample function calls.

The `updateMatchesBetweenTeams` checks if a match with the same home vs away teams already exists and increases its `matchesPlayed` counter, otherwise creates a new entry with `matchesPlayed: 1`.

The `updateTableOfMatches` clears and refills a table showing all matches stored so far. Columns of the table are Home, Away and Matches Played.

For docs of the used DOM APIs see [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) and [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```js
document.getElementById("add-teams").addEventListener("click", addTeams);
  
function addTeams() {
    const homeTeam = document.getElementById('homeInput').value;
    const awayTeam = document.getElementById('awayInput').value;

    // homeTeam and awayTeam contain the text from inputs
    // now you can call other functions in your code and pass these values in
    
    updateMatchesBetweenTeams(matches, homeTeam, awayTeam)

    updateTableOfMatches(matches)
}

// Matches should contain objects with structure
// { homeTeam: string, awayTeam: string, matchesPlayed: number }
const matches = []

function updateMatchesBetweenTeams(matches, homeTeam, awayTeam) {
    const match = matches.find(it => it.homeTeam === homeTeam && it.awayTeam === awayTeam)
    if (match) {
      // entry already exists, so just update it
      match.matchesPlayed++
    } else {
      // create a new entry
      // { homeTeam, awayTeam } is shorthand for { homeTeam: homeTeam, awayTeam: awayTeam }
      matches.push({ homeTeam, awayTeam, matchesPlayed: 1 })
    }
    return matches
}

function updateTableOfMatches(matches) {
    const tbody = document.getElementById('matches-table-body')
    // clear the table first
    tbody.textContent = ''
    for (let match of matches) {
        const columnValues = [match.homeTeam, match.awayTeam, match.matchesPlayed]
        tbody.appendChild(createTableRow(columnValues))
    }
}

function createTableRow(columnValues) {
    const tableRow = document.createElement("tr")

    for (let columnValue of columnValues) {
      const td = document.createElement("td")
      td.textContent = columnValue
      // or td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(columnValue))
      tableRow.appendChild(td)
    }
    
    return tableRow
}
```

```html
<label for="home">Home Team</label>
<input type="text" id="homeInput" name="fname"><br><br>
<label for="home">Away Team</label>
<input type="text" id="awayInput" name="fname"><br><br>

<button type="button" id="add-teams">Add Teams</button>

<p>The table below shows all matches between the teams</p>

<table id="matches-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Home</th>
      <th>Away</th>
      <th>Matches Played</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="matches-table-body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please stop using unsafe inline `on*`. JS should be in one place only, and that's its respective tag or file. Also, `<button>` by default is `type="submit"`, so use from finger memory `type="button"` - unless submit is needed.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That was copy paste code from OP. I changed that part as well.